# Newlines in Wordpress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I just set up a blog on Wordpress.com, and the problem is, if I write:

```
something something

blah blah
```

That empty line in between doesn't show up! What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress.com and self-hosted strips extra white space. But you can try forcing a new line with a nonbreaking space in between bold tags:

```
<b>&nbsp;</b>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you would need the `<b>` tags? I've always just forced a line break with `<br>` when I've had to...